# Chain Rule Probability

Tags: probability

I can't, for the life of me, understand chain rule on conditional distributions of random variables. I can't see the pattern. Like, how do I find out what things like these are:

P(A,B|C)

P(X,Y,Z|W)

P(U|V,W)

P(M|N,O,P)

P(H,I|J,K)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joint probability of events $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ conditioned on events $B_1,B_2,...,B_k$ is equal to the joint probability of $A_1,A_2,...,A_n,B_1,B_2,...,B_k$ divided by the joint probability of $B_1,B_2,...,B_k$. In other words,

$$ P(A_1,A_2,...,A_n | B_1,B_2,...,B_k) = \frac{P(A_1,A_2,...,A_n,B_1,B_2,...,B_k)}{P(B_1,B_2,...,B_k)} $$

Further manipulations of the above quotient can be performed using the general multiplication rule

$$ P(E_1,E_2,...,E_n) = P(E_1)P(E_2|E_1)P(E_3|E_1,E_2) ... P(E_n|E_1,E_2,...,E_{n-1}) $$

or [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: So, for example using my first question above, P(A,B|C) = P(A,B,C)/P(C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)?

Comment: And similarly, P(X,Y,Z|W) = P(X,Y,Z,W)/P(W) = P(X,Y|Z,W)P(Z|W) ?

Comment: Yes, everything you just said is correct!

Comment: There are so many ways I could split up each expression. For instance:
P(A,B|C) = P(A,B,C)/P(C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C) = P(B|A,C)P(A|C) = P(C|B,A)P(B|A)P(A)/P(C) ....
Is there an intuitive way to guide which chain I go down? When ever I apply chain rule to exam questions, I always seem to go down the wrong chain.

Comment: Can I use A* pathfinding to navigate the tree of chains?

Comment: there are indeed many ways of expressing a conditional probability like the one you described. The expression that is most advantageous is going to depend on what your end goal is. if you gave me some example questions, then perhaps I could assist you (in fact, some example questions would be excellent posts on the Math SE).

Comment: $A^*$ is a search algorithm that finds the minimum cost path between two states, a start state and goal state. To you use it, you'd need to define a cost (or reward) function to compute a cost (or reward) associated with each possible state, or expression, and you'd need a heuistic function to estimate the cost beween a given expression and the goal state. Your idea of using $A^*$ is intriguing, but I can't think of a way to implement it nor have I seen it done for this purpose. Main challenge I see is not knowing the goal state because you don't know the answer to the problem you're solving.